# Pyinstaller-created-program Prerequisites

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, pyinstaller

I recently broke a solid state drive so I had to reinstall windows etc. After a fresh install, a program I created with pyinstaller wouldn't open or give me an error message. Now that I have installed Visual Studio 2012, it works fine. I'm assuming VS comes with a bunch of redistributables, one or more of which is required for pyinstaller. Does anyone know what it is so I can inform my users?

Edit: I uninstalled every visual c++ redistributable and .Net framework and it still works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this, I believe I narrowed it down to this redistributable package https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=30679